# How do I use a keyboard shortcut to execute a shell script I wrote, passing the file selected in Finder as an arg?

Tags: keyboard, finder, script, command-line

I suppose you could have it pass in whatever was selected in general in any app (such as text highlighted in a web browser).

Answer (score 1):

Use Automator. Generate a .app. A keyboard shortcut can launch the app, and Automator knows how to grab the Finder selections, which it can then pass to the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, assuming you're using Snow Leopard, is to create an automator service and assign a keyboard shortcut to it using System Preferences.

Here's a tutorial to get you started:

http://www.pixelcorps.tv/macbreak235